# Rare error in Eclipse with brackets and ";"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to test some things with java but I have the following errors:

In line 16: Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

In line 36: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

I've already inserted a bracket in line 36 but in principle is not necessary...and the error in line 16 persists

Someone could help me to detect what is the problem?

Thank you so much.

Here is the code i'm using for the class NewsCrawler.java:

```
package upf.dad.proyecto;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;

public class NewsCrawler {

        URL url = new URL("https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=t&ned=es&output=rss"); 
        XmlReader reader = null;


    try {   
        reader = new XmlReader(url);    
        SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);

        for (Iterator i = feed.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
                System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle());
                System.out.println("   Description: " + Jsoup.parse(entry.getDescription().getValue()).text());
                System.out.println("   Date: " + entry.getPublishedDate());       
                System.out.println("   Link: " + entry.getLink());    
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {       
            reader.close();    
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: put your code into a method

Comment: @Reimeus The whole code?

Comment: Yes.  You can't just throw code into a class without a method or constructor around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing constructor?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;

public class NewsCrawler
{
    public NewsCrawler()
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=t&ned=es&output=rss");
        XmlReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new XmlReader(url);
            SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);

            for (Iterator i = feed.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();)
            {
                SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
                System.out.println("Title: " + entry.getTitle());
                System.out.println("   Description: " + Jsoup.parse(entry.getDescription().getValue()).text());
                System.out.println("   Date: " + entry.getPublishedDate());
                System.out.println("   Link: " + entry.getLink());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```